# Shopware 6 Performance while experiencing Peaks

Tags: php, performance, shopware, shopware6

We manage a Shopware 6.4.15 shop on behalf of our client.

In the recent past, a new, product was launched with a limited quantity, which generated a strong rush (approx. 50-60 requests / second) to the shop.
The customers tried to click on the product and sometimes, not always, got a 404 error message, whereas others were able to buy the item without any problems, since there is a steady stream of orders in the view.

Is it possible that the Shopware system redirects these loads to a 404 page?
We cannot explain this behavior. It occurred regardless of the operating system and browser, as well as referrer and time.
It required a cache flush to work again, but I am not quite sure why this worked

Normally I would expect that in the case of an overloaded Server a HTTP 500 Error is thrown, as well as consequent, not sporadic.

Comment: I would be very surprised if there is an intentional redirect to 404 in case of load problems. How does the 404 message look like? Is it really from Shopware? which response code does the server's access.log contain? Any way to reproduce this locally? for example with `siege` ? Any errors in `var/log/prod*.log`?